# entering if statements without initializing

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, dtmf

I'm writing a C++ program library for my Arduino. The library is for a DTMF decoder. I'm having a problem when it comes to adding two detected and validated tones together in order to return the corresponding button.

I call the function below twice (it's not entirely finished but you'll hopefully get my logic). If I initialise the values R1 & R2 to 0 then they overwrite each other on the second call. If I don't initialise them at all I get a run time check error.

I've spend at 40+ hours trying to figure this out (I'm a very basic level coder!). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    int DTMF::validate(void)
    {
        int threshhold = 9000;
        int i;
        int x;
        int y;
    //  int high[7];

        for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if(magnitude[i] > threshhold)
            {
                return(i);  
            }
        }
    }

unsigned char DTMF::buttonPressed(void)
{
    int validatedFreq = validate();
    cout << "valid is returning: " << validatedFreq << endl;
    int R1;
    int R2;

    switch(validatedFreq)
    {

        case 0:
            R1=1;
            cout << "DEBUG:This is case 1 R1 output: " << R1 << endl;
            break;

        case 1:
            R1=2;
            break;

        case 2:
            R1=3;
            break;

        case 3:
            R2=4;
            cout << "DEBUG:This is case 3 R2 output: " << R2 << endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            R2=5;
            break;

        case 5:
            R2=6;
            break;

        case 6:
            R2=7;
            break;
    }

    if(R1==1 && R2==4)
    {
        cout << "DEBUG:The value of R1 is " << R1 << " and the value of R2 is " << R2 << endl;
        return(button[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with _they overwrite each other_? this code looks ok at a first glance...what's the expected output and what's the output you get?

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R2 are **local variables**, since you declared them inside the function. This means that they are initialized every time you call the function, and every time you do, R1 and R2 are two new int variables.

If you want their values to stay the same between different calls of the function you could declare them as `static`. This makes it so that they are only initialized once everytime you run the program. You do it with

`static int R2;`

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! If only I had asked for help sooner I would be that much less behind in this project.

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R2 are local and automatic to the DTMF::buttonPressed function, so they don't persist between the calls.

If you don't initialize them, you must assign them before you can assume they have whatever meaningful value. But your switch assign only one of them. But you later pretend to use them both in the following `if`.

Whatever behavior you can observe, at that point, is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `R1` and `R2` into the class `DTMF` members (move them to header). Then you should initialize them to zero in constructor and check if the **both** are non-zero before `if(R1==1 && R2==4)`. Like this:

```
// header:
class DTMF {
...
int R1;
int R2;
}
// cpp
DTMF::DTMF() : R1( 0 ), R2( 0 ) { ... }

unsigned char DTMF::buttonPressed(void)
{
    int validatedFreq = validate();
    cout << "valid is returning: " << validatedFreq << endl;
    //int R1;
    //int R2;

    // fill R1 or R2 exactly as you did

    if ( R1 != 0 && R2 != 0 && R1==1 && R2==4 ) {
        ...
        R1 = R2 = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. The static int suggestion worked. However, my output just shows some weird symbol instead of the char '1'.

Comment: That looks like a good approach too though static int seems to have worked a treat for me.

Comment: If you'll use static you cannot create two instances of DTMF class